# EC2 or GAE for python/django app

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am currently deciding whether to use EC2 or GAE for my django app. I've done some research on both. In terms of deploying a database-driven django app with the following:

```
-- high on db reads / moderate db writes in mysql
-- memcached
-- ffmpeg (though not for video transcoding)
```

what are the pros / cons of each? My main considerations are:

```
-- ease of setting up
-- ease of scaling up /down
-- speed (for EC2 this is easy to figure out)
-- uptime
```

Additionally, how would they compare in cost with GAE's recent increases? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Update: After I wrote this answer, Google announced support for their own hosted version of MySQL named [Google Cloud SQL](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-cloud-sql-your-database-in-cloud.html).  Wooble also points out that Google supports memcached as well.*

<strike>If you need to run MySQL <strike>and memcached</strike> then you can't use GAE.</strike> GAE does provide it's own data store API if you can convert to using that: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

You can't run ffmpeg on GAE.  I don't know if there is any pure Python implementation of such functionality.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872388/

All of this can be done on EC2 as you're just running standard Linux (or Windows) servers and installing and configuring your own software.

Comment: App Engine has memcache; in fact, Brad Fitzpatrick (founder of Livejournal, where he invented memcached) has worked on the App Engine team.

Comment: Wooble: Thanks for the correction.  I was answering on the edge of what I know about and will move back towards the center of my areas of expertise :-)